# WSO2 calling multiple APIs in Proxy Service

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

it is possible to call multiple API in insequence ?
I have two APIs
1. Get API, which returns a list of stings.

Response:

```
[
    "23001790",
    "23001807",
    "23001789",
    "23001793",
    "23001794"
]
```

2. Post API, which takes a list of strings as input in body.

response:

```
[
    {
        "location_code": "0",
        "natural_account": "52403",
        "department_code": "262",
        "debit_amount": 14.8,
        "credit_amount": 14.8,
        "creation_date": "2023-03-29"
    },
    {
        "location_code": "0",
        "natural_account": "61151",
        "department_code": "221",
        "debit_amount": 100,
        "credit_amount": 100,
        "creation_date": "2023-03-29"
    },
    {
        "location_code": "5",
        "natural_account": "61152",
        "department_code": "221",
        "debit_amount": 2000,
        "credit_amount": 2000,
        "creation_date": "2023-03-29"
    },
    {
        "location_code": "5",
        "natural_account": "61155",
        "department_code": "221",
        "debit_amount": 400,
        "credit_amount": 400,
        "creation_date": "2023-03-29"
    }
]
```

and modify respose by adding some more values

I'm using wo2 management studio with micro integrator
I wrote a proxy service because its a schedule task.

or do have any othe option to achieve that?

I attempted it in this manner:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="ErpProxyService" startOnLoad="true" statistics="enable" trace="enable" transports="http https" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <log level="custom">
                <property name="ERPScheduler" value="ERP Scheduler started"/>
            </log>
            <log level="custom">
                <property name="API call" value="Calling Get1BillChallanAPI"/>
            </log>
            <property expression="concat(get-property('file', 'BaseUrl'), get-property('file', 'getonebillchallans'))" name="uri.var.x" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property expression="concat(get-property('file', 'BaseUrl'), get-property('file', 'getErpData'))" name="uri.var.y" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <log level="custom">
                <property expression="get-property('uri.var.x')" name="uri.var.x"/>
                <property expression="get-property('uri.var.y')" name="uri.var.y"/>
            </log>
            <call>
                <endpoint>
                    <http method="get" uri-template="{uri.var.x}">
                        <suspendOnFailure>
                            <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                            <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
                            <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                        </suspendOnFailure>
                        <markForSuspension>
                            <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                        </markForSuspension>
                    </http>
                </endpoint>
            </call>
            <log level="full"/>
            <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                <format>{"response": $1}</format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <log level="custom">
                <property name="API call" value="Calling GetERPdata"/>
            </log>
            <property expression="$body" name="response" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <log level="custom">
                <property name="API call" expression="get-property('response')"/>
            </log>
            <call>
                <endpoint>
                    <http method="post" uri-template="{uri.var.y}">
                        <suspendOnFailure>
                            <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                            <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
                            <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                        </suspendOnFailure>
                        <markForSuspension>
                            <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                        </markForSuspension>
                    </http>
                </endpoint>
            </call>

            <log level="full"/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
</proxy>
```

Comment: Yes, the way you are doing it correct? Are you seeing any issues?

Comment: yes I'm not getting the payload in response of 2nd API

Comment: @ebadmahmood Can you enable wire logs and verify it? https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/develop/using-wire-logs/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is very much possible, and this is one of the very common use cases for Micro-iintegrator. This is referred to as Service Orchestration.

You need to use `Call` mediator to call 1st service. Get the response and store it using `PayloadFactory` mediator. And then use another `Call` mediator to send that payload as a request body.

Refer this for more details - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/tutorials/integration-tutorials/exposing-several-services-as-a-single-service/